# Update or append JAVA_HOME with sed

Tags: sed, scripting, java, variable

I am scripting my new VM stack and I am trying to update or append `JAVA_HOME` in the `~/.bashrc` file

I've managed to do that by running the following `sed` command from the command line.

```
sed '/export[ ]JAVA_HOME=/{h;s/=.*/='"updatedJava"'/};${x;/^$/{s//export JAVA_HOME='"newJava"'/;H};x}' -i ~/.bashrc
```

However, when I try to run it from a script using a variable, I am getting the  following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unknown option to `s'

I figured out that it is caused due to fact that my path contain `/` which is confused with the `sed` delimiter, therefore I've changed it to this:

```
 sed '/export[ ]JAVA_HOME=/{h;s#=.*#='$java'#};${x;/^$/{s##export JAVA_HOME='$java'#;H};x}' -i ~/.bashrc
```

where `$java` contains a path to java, however now it doesn't work, it also doesn't throw any exception. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I want to check if there is already "export JAVA_HOME=" in .bashrc and update it with correct value (hold in $java variable) . In case it doesn't exist I want to append it to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your logic, I have recast the `sed` in a slightly compact form, wherein, the change to the JAVA_HOME is done once at the beginning of the sed.

Plus, there's this bit about escaping the java variable so that it is fit to be included into the `rhs` of a `s///` `sed` command.

Plus, the `sed` is `POSIX`-ly.

```
java_esc=$(printf '%s\n' "$java" | sed -e 's|[\&/]|\\&|g;$!s/$/\\/')

sed -i.BAK -e '
   1{
      x
      s/.*/export JAVA_HOME='"$java_esc"'/
      x
   }

   # assuming the JAVA_HOME declaration does not span line boundaries
   /^[[:blank:]]*export[[:blank:]]\{1,\}JAVA_HOME=/{
      g
      x
      s/^/\
/
      x
   }

   ${
      x
      /^\n/!H
      x
   }
' ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: It's throwing "sed: can't read .BAK: No such file or directory" however it's doing the main job correctly

Comment: @DawidAdach Fixed. No space between `i` and backup extension.

Comment: I have odd issue. After removing space as you suggested entire script stopped working :( what is even more surprising, once i revert to the previous version it doesn't append nor update the ~/.bashrc file. $java_esc echo shows correctly escaped path. Is it possible that it has something to do with BAK file? some file permissions? I separated only your code and java path (checked twice and it doesn't work anymore), any idea? (running as sudo)

Comment: OK, that's odd... I just found the answer. The reason was that I was runnig script with sudo. Without sudo it works like a charm and replaces everything... I am leaving second comment in case someone else face the same issue in a future

Answer (score 0):

The second command has dropped the `"` characters from the replacement string.  And I don't understand what you are doing with the `s` at the end, so how about:

```
sed '/export \{1,\}JAVA_HOME=/{h;s#=.*#="'$java'"#};${x;/^$/{s##export JAVA_HOME="'$java'"#;H};x}' -i ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: No result neither :( you can check yourself adding java="/sample/path/to/java" . JAVA_HOME= is not beeing appended to the file

Comment: Did it work for you? It still doesn't work for me :( I jus tried with no luck

Comment: I've set "export JAVA_HOME=temp" inside ~/.bashrc, unfortunately after running the script doesn't affect file

Comment: The `+` quantifier in `/export +JAVA_HOME=/` isn't portable I don't think - (and where it is supported, it probably requires extended mode `-E` or `-r`) - try either `/export  *JAVA_HOME=/` (that's two spaces and a star) or `/export \{1,\}JAVA_HOME=/` for one or more space characters

Comment: @DawidAdach, updated with comments.